# PHP _POST Array

Tags: php, post

I am wondering why: without clicking the submit button on a form on my PHP page, the `_POST` variable is already set.

For example, I have this piece of code on the web page:

```
if (isset($_POST)){
     echo "XXXXXXX";
}
```

It turns out the `XXXXXX` is echoed just when the page loads the very first time -- at this point I have of course not submitted any data to the server using POST. Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` is a superglobal array and it is always set. If you do not pass any value to it using post method it will be empty. So set a value to this array and check whether that value is available or not like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 //Do this...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), it is automatically created.

> This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.

To address your code, it **is** created, but it's empty.

To better test if the user has made a `POST` request, simply test for an index on `$_POST`, like `isset($_POST['someFieldName'])`

Your code should test if it's empty or not:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    echo "a";
}
```

or

```
if(isset($_POST['someFieldName'])){
     echo "a";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the variable is empty or not. `$_POST` will always be set.

So something like the following should work:

```
if(!empty($_POST['textFieldName'])){
    echo "XXXXXXX";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same is true for the `$_GET` superglobal. These are always set regardless of HTTP Method. You can check if a request was a `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, etc by checking the `REQUEST_METHOD`

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // this was an HTTP POST request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is superglobal and it's always set as an empty array.
Try this, just to understand better:

```
if(!is_null($_POST))
{
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Why is this going to help you to understand? - Because isset checking if a variable is set and is not NULL.